# NFS file owner(uid) = 4294967294, can't do much with my mount, How do I fix this?

Tags: linux, users, nfs, android

I have a somewhat strange setup going on here, I have Android as the client and it's kernel does not support NFSv4, also my /etc/exports file on the server side has no NFSv4 style entries.

I am trying to build some toolchains (I have gcc-4.8-armhf and all that on my phone as well as apt-get with repositories set up so I can install stuff if needed) as well as following LFS, but I can't build some programs such as perl due to not being able set file ownership and what not.

My /etc/exports (server) :

```
/media/usb3/Android     192.168.1.209(rw,sync,subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

A `ls -l` looks like this (client):

```
drwxr-xr-x  6 4294967294 4294967294      4096 Jun 21 17:23 toolchains
-rw-r--r--  1 4294967294 4294967294         0 Jun 25 18:51 rootu
```

A `sudo chown root:root` looks like this (client) (rootu is just a test file):

```
sudo chown root:root rootu
chown: changing ownership of `rootu': Invalid argument
```

My mount command (client) :

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.210:/media/usb3/Android /home/edge-case/Android-Lab/ -o tcp
```

I've gone over the man pages and read some tutorials and other questions but they all say to just set no_root_squash, which I did from the start, and that doesn't work.

I don't have LDAP or Kerberos, or any sophisticated authentication set up at the moment, that is all beyond my skill ( and 0 pay ) level at the moment. I'm at home so I have complete root access and ownership of everything and not too worried about security other than maybe war-drivers, but I do have a good wireless password, so no tin foil hat really needed for me ;P

I used to have this working, but it seems some changes to Debian have been made and things are not working so well anymore. Are Windows agents screwing up Linux source!? J/k

Really what is this? Where can I find a simple way to mount a directory with files owned by me, or root (via sudo chown) if I choose, and not some strange "4294967294" user that doesn't exist on the client or server?

Comment: Please make your update an answer - you can just answer yourself. You can still get better answers, but at least it will not stay formally unanswered forever.

Comment: Thanks, will do tomorrow after 8 hours have passed, said I need to wait until 4 some a.m.

Answer (score 1):

I hate it when I figure this out right after asking the question,

I used
`/system/xbin/busybox mount -t nfs /path/to/share /path/to/mountpoint -o tcp,nolock`

It works, now my files are owned my my user "10001:10001" on the client, but its a messy solution because if I use the Cyanogenmod's `busybox mount` without the `nolock` option it gets permission denied, but if I use Debian's mount with the `nolock` option it still has the strange UID:GID ownership.

So currently the only way to work is with Cyanogenmod's `busybox mount` with `nolock`. Using `nolock` with Debian's `mount` wont fix the id issue and without `nolock` on Cyangenmod's I get permission denied.

I guess the proper solution would be to go over the source for each and rebuild Debian's `mount` command with a patch to be like Cyan's and to figure out why I need `nolock`, I don't think I should need that. Maybe it's a linker/library issue? Idk, beyond me atm.